# CSS floats, change order on mobile layout?

Tags: css

I have a regular layout that looks that this:
[image]

This layout is done using CSS floats.

When I switch to mobile, I want my layout to do this:

[image]

That is, I want my sidebar to be **below** the content. I can do this using absolute positioning, but I was wondering, is there a way to do this using floats so that if my content changes the sidebar will adjust for the height difference?

Comment: What if the content has `float:left`, but also as a `width` that will use up all the available viewport? Wouldn't the sidebar be shifted underneath?

Comment: Fixed until the user resizes to a mobile width

Comment: I tried with just floats but doesn't work...maybe because I had the sidebar div before the content div?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.  The DIVs are floated on your desktop version, but displayed on top of eachother (default `block` display) on mobile.

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}

.mobile #sidebar,
.mobile #content {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Standard HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
...
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
...
</div>
</body>
```

Mobile HTML:

```
<body class="mobile">
<div id="content">
...
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
...
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Media query, `flex` container and its `order` property should do the trick:

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .content {
        order: 1;
    }
    .sidebar {
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

Make sure to replace `max-width` value with your own mobile breakpoint.

[Browser support for flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) is also pretty decent now.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

1. The two elements have a shared parent element
2. The content div appears BEFORE the sidebar in the source

You don't have to change the source order, you can achieve this with floats by default.

That is, in your desktop layout:

```
#content {
   float: right;
   width: 60%;
}

#sidebar {
   float: left;
   width: 40%;
}
```

Then, for mobile (using media queries or whatever other mechanism):

```
#content, #sidebar {
   float: none;
   clear: both;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your mobile media queries set `float:none`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I wanted to set layout like first layout so I had used:

```
        .iconHome{
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #73AD21;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: aqua;

            /*margin: 50px;*/
        }

    <div class="iconHome1">


    </div>

    <div class="iconHome1">


    </div>
```

The result is the second layout!!!There fore, I think default "float:left" is not be set on mobile. You can use above way. Hope help you

**Edit:**

I tried some codes:

```
        .iconHome1{
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #73AD21;
            width: 50%;/*185px*/
            height: 200px;
            background-color: aqua;
            margin: 0;/*0 0 0 -7px*/
            /*clear: left;*/
        }
```

### [image]

That means "width" & "margin" will effect to layout,although you have to set "float:left". Fix "width:49%", result:

[image]