# CSS Overflow With Divs within Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a new design and have been stuck on a design aspect which appears to only be fixed with some connection to the css attribute overflow, that or some form of javascript.

This is how my site boxes would normally look:

[image]

But if a screen is too small, this is how it looks:

[image]

So would it be better to fix this problem with css or javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Although you have provided a link to an example or site, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem

Comment: You should do this using css only. JavaScript would be overkill.

Comment: @randy - gotcha, I have fixed it with css, figured someone would tell me which was the either more difficult/exhausting idea. Thanks!

Comment: @MukeshRam - in the future, since this is just a local site (for the time being) would it be helpful to post just the specific html and then all of the css? And thanks for the welcome!

Comment: @Matthew Post the [minimum HTML and CSS required](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce. Preferably in a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), not external ( like JSFiddle )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly where your problem because your not post your code/fiddle/website. But it be better to fix your problem using CSS, because it happen to your style. Try to make different style on different size screen. hope this link help you [CSS Media Screen](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by updating the CSS file code,
Please check the CSS float change for mobile size in the below link.

[CSS floats, change order on mobile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485493/css-floats-change-order-on-mobile-layout)